# Java Installation in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, sdk, jre

I installed java from Oracle website  ([here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u27-download-440405.HTML).) the last one  **Windows x64**, but when I try to set the path there is no JDK folder inside the installation folder. There is jre folder there but it doesn't show any version number. How can I fix this issue, because I need to run jruby on Windows for that I want Java as well.

Comment: The JRE is the runtime, are yousure you need the SDK for jRuby to run ?

Comment: Yes I need JDK.

Answer (score 1):

The download path tell you the jdk version is Java6 update 27, you can run java -version to verify the version.

Comment: Thanks..I run the command java-version i got 1.7.0 but in the installed folder there is not jdk folder all I have is 

bin db demo include jre(no version number) lib sample and some files. My question is how could I set the path in windows as there is not jdk folder

Comment: There is no 'jdk' folder in jdk. Just set path to 'bin' folder if you want to run javac from command line.

Comment: I put like this JAVA_HOME C:\development\java\bin Then I got a message Can not locate java installation specified by JAVA_HOME C:\development\java\bin\java.exe

Comment: I am afraid executing java -version does not tell you if you have a jdk.

Comment: You should set JAVA_HOME to jdk root path.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid executing java -version will not tell you if you have a jdk. By default JDK is installed under Program FIles like in my case it is here C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22

Check out the similar location on your box and see if it has `javac` . If you find javac under bin then, you have the jdk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I changed the location of Java installation to something different C:\development\Java\bin, under this bin file there is a javac.exe file. Any way I will try your method as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks...I installed to programfile location and it works..Thanks..

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to re-install the JDK. If you had it at some other location then, you just need to set JAVA_HOME=c:\some_other_location and it will work as @zhongshu has pointed out.